# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD., but i have to use post method only

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

This is the code I used in the blade file:

```
<form action="addTo_cart" method="post">
```

This is the route I used in the web.php

```
Route::post("/addTo_cart",[ProductController::class, 'addToCart']);
```

and I got the error that,

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: can you provide more detail where you are posting to this route for example blade template etc...

Comment: add specific code from where the error is generating.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize your route like this

`Route::match(['get',post] , 'View-name' , 'Controller@function-name');`

Your route should be like this

`Route::match(['get','post'],"/addTo_cart",[ProductController::class, 'addToCart']);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you to add a name to your route like this

```php
Route::post("/addTo_cart",[ProductController::class, 'addToCart'])->name('cart.addToCart');
```

After that, I would rewrite the action of your form to use the name of the route you just added

```php
<form action="{{route('cart.addproduct')}}" method="post">
```

Also, don't forget your csrf token. The "finished" form should look something like this

```php
<form action="{{route('cart.addproduct')}}" method="post">
@csrf
<input name="exampleInput">
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

And also make sure you are accepting the Request in your controller (example)

```php
 public function addToCart(Request $request)
 {
        dd($request); //dump the request on the page so you can have a look at it
        //more code
 }
```